# Apache SSL not working

Tags: apache, ssl, https

- Apache 2.2 on debian-based Linux
- `# a2enmod ssl && service apache2 restart`
- Port 443 is closed according to SheildsUP! scan, but not in stealth mode
- Apache is listening on ports 80 and 443 according to `netstat -nutlp`
- Hosting the same website on port 80 and port 443
- http://website.com works, https://website.com does not

My virtual host setup is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine               On
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   SSL_DIR/ssl.key
    SSLCertificateFile      SSL_DIR/ssl.crt
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
    ServerAdmin     webmaster@localhost
    ServerAlias     website.com *.website.com
    ServerName      www.website.com

    # Just a few connection resets so that I don't waste my bandwidth on "hackers"
    SecRuleEngine On
    SecRule &REQUEST_HEADERS:User-Agent     "@eq 0"         drop,phase:1
    SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:User-Agent      "^$"            drop,phase:1

    SecRule REQUEST_LINE                    "://"           drop,phase:1

    SecRule REQUEST_URI                     "^/admin"       drop,phase:1
    SecRule REQUEST_URI                     "^/mail"        drop,phase:1
    SecRule REQUEST_URI                     "^/webmail"     drop,phase:1

    DocumentRoot /path/public_html
    <Directory /path/public_html/>
            Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I also got 2 `.pem` files when I registered my SSL certificate, and can't find anything about what to do with them.

My question is, why is SSL not working? Is it related to the `.pem` files?

Comment: Off topic; belongs on serverfault.com.

Comment: I'm not sure. This is a home server, which Server Fault specifically says not to ask questions about.

Comment: In that case it belongs on superuser.com. It's not a programming question.

Comment: Alright. Thank you for informing me. I'll try posting this there once this closes.

Comment: But why wait? That's where you'll get an answer. It's in your own interest. It's off-topic here and on-topic there, so you're less likely to get a reliable answer here than there. Do it now.

Comment: Yeah. I kind of realized that a while ago, and I've already re-posted the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

first of all, you have to enable ssl

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
```

and than you have to include your pem file (mini example)

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        SSLEngine               On
        SSLCertificateKeyFile   SSL_DIR/ssl.key
        SSLCertificateFile      SSL_DIR/ssl.crt

        ServerAdmin     webmaster@localhost
        ServerAlias     website.com *.website.com
        ServerName      www.website.com

        # Just a few connection resets so that I don't waste my bandwidth on "hackers"
        SecRuleEngine On
        SecRule &REQUEST_HEADERS:User-Agent     "@eq 0"         drop,phase:1
        SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:User-Agent      "^$"            drop,phase:1

        SecRule REQUEST_LINE                    "://"           drop,phase:1

        SecRule REQUEST_URI                     "^/admin"       drop,phase:1
        SecRule REQUEST_URI                     "^/mail"        drop,phase:1
        SecRule REQUEST_URI                     "^/webmail"     drop,phase:1

        DocumentRoot /path/public_html
        <Directory /path/public_html/>
                Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin     webmaster@localhost
        ServerAlias     website.com *.website.com
        ServerName      www.website.com

        # Just a few connection resets so that I don't waste my bandwidth on "hackers"
        SecRuleEngine On
        SecRule &REQUEST_HEADERS:User-Agent     "@eq 0"         drop,phase:1
        SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:User-Agent      "^$"            drop,phase:1

        SecRule REQUEST_LINE                    "://"           drop,phase:1

        SecRule REQUEST_URI                     "^/admin"       drop,phase:1
        SecRule REQUEST_URI                     "^/mail"        drop,phase:1
        SecRule REQUEST_URI                     "^/webmail"     drop,phase:1

        DocumentRoot /path/public_html
        <Directory /path/public_html/>
                Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I enabled SSL already (which I forgot to state). I've tried both `.pem` files, and they both resulted in `[error] SSL Library Error: 185073780 error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch`. If I try not including the private key (like in your example), Apache fails to start because there's no private key.

Comment: you are totally right. the .pem file is the master file, and than you generate the .key file from the .pem file. So i dont know why my documentation points on the .pem file. However, try to set all parameters (like servername, alias, ..) in the <VirtualHost *:443> section

Comment: That made no difference. It was worth a try though.

Comment: i am worried about the "<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>"

Comment: I tried the 2 different blocks. No difference. Thanks for the try.

Comment: I will review my server config when I am back home and give you a response than. What does the error log show?

Comment: That's the thing; there is nothing in the Apache error logs or `/var/log/syslog`. It's like it's not hitting the system even though the port is open.

Comment: I asked this again on [Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/597499/apache-ssl-not-working) if you're still interested.

Comment: Turns out that even though port 80 is open, my ISP is blocking port 443. Just thought you might want some closure on this. Thank you for your time.